# Examples of Abelian rings

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. an element $e$ in $R$ is idempotent if $e^2=e$. we say that $R$ is Abelian if for each $x \in R$ and each idempotent $e \in R$ we have $ex=xe$. 
$R$ is commutative if for each $a,b \in R$ we have $ab=ba$.
is there any example of the Abelian ring that is not commutative?

Comment: usually Abelian and commutative are synonymous

Comment: but see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/820302) of @rschwieb

Comment: I give the definition. please answer the question by the definition.

Comment: In my experience, abelian to mean "commutative" is kind of out of date, but abelian to mean "all idempotents central" is more modern but also a little obscure. It's good you included the definition in your post.

Answer (score 1):

In counterpoint to noncommutative reduced rings, you also have noncommutative local rings. The only idempotents there are $0,1$ which are always central, but here you can have nilpotent elements.

It also turns out there is an example [due to Chase](https://ringtheory.herokuapp.com/rings/ring/39/) that is neither local nor reduced. If the link ever breaks you can find it here:

> T.Y. Lam. Lectures on modules and rings. (2012) pp 47-48

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Take any [non-commutative reduced ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3414184/examples-of-non-commutative-reduced-rings). In reduced rings [idempotents are central](https://ysharifi.wordpress.com/tag/central-idempotent/).